# My app crashes, trying to add a menu

Tags: java, android, performance, menu

I have added a menu in a simple app of hello world! But my app keeps crashing. 
I am not adding my xml code. My xml file name is menu inside the menu folder in res. 
Here is my java file.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu1){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu1);                //line 19
    return true;
}
```

**Logcat**

```
    06-03 18:03:57.682 13542-13542/com.example.kaushalraj.a424 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kaushalraj.a424, PID: 13542
android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler action in class com.example.kaushalraj.a424.MainActivity
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:253)
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:481)
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:529)
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:205)
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:127)
    at com.example.kaushalraj.a424.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3388)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:364)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1657)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:134)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: action [interface android.view.MenuItem]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:481) 
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:529) 
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:205) 
    at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:127) 
    at com.example.kaushalraj.a424.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3388) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:364) 
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1377) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1657) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:134) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Is that the full logcat that you have pasted? If not, please paste in the full logcat. Also you said your menu file name is `menu`. Or is it `menu1`?

Comment: On line 19, ` inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu1); ` is there really a comma ? It should be dot (.)

Comment: @ravi no that's not full logcat

Comment: Replace inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu1) with inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu) and onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu1) with onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) if your menu's name is   menu1.

Comment: @ravi yeah..that's comma! I have removed that comma.

Comment: @KaushalRaj Please do make the changes and paste in the full logcat.

Comment: @ravi i have done everything you have said,still app is crashing.

Comment: @KaushalRaj The logcat please. And do check @Michail Ai 's answer to see which theme your `res/calues/styles.xml` has.

Comment: my menu file name is menu.xml, i have done the followig changes

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

Comment: Is there @Override just above onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: action`

Comment: @ravi yes,there is override.

Comment: Can you paste your menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this your case (and i don't have the reputation to comment) but: What app theme are you using? If you are using a theme that does not have a actionbar at the top then you will get this error when you try to attach your menu to it, as the actionbar does not exist.

You have two solutions:

1. Check your theme in res/values/styles.xml if you are using something like *Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar* you must change it to something like *Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*. This will add the actionbar to your activity.
2. Using the support toolbar library, add the toolbar to your activity xml layout then from your activity class get the view in OnCreate() and use `setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)`. This will set your toolbar view as the actionbar where your menu will be attached to.

Comment: No, I have added tool bar.